# Can't connect my php code to sql server db

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, database-connection

My site is hosting on windows server and I'm using php 7.3.4 and already have installed drivers. Using these two extensions in my php.ini file

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64
```

The code I'm using is bellow. I've tried so many ways but none of them was success.

Please can someone give me a hand

```
$serverName = ip_addr_of_server;
    $database = name_of_db;
    $uid = user_name;
    $pwd = password;
    try {
        $dbDB = new PDO(
            "sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=$database",
            $uid,
            $pwd
        );
        $dbDB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message and how do you know that this code does not work? Test extension with simple PHP script: `<?php phpinfo();?>` - there must be a section `pdo_sqlsrv`.

Comment: @Zhorov I got this
pdo_sqlsrv 
support   enabled
ExtensionVer      5.6.1+11919

Comment: Then just check for errors with `catch` block:`try {$dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=$database", $uid, $pwd);$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);} catch( PDOException $e ) {die( "Error connecting to SQL Server" );}; echo "OK";`. Your code is correct and should work, if your server name and database name are correct, and SQL Server is configured correctly.